# How can I create a VPN connection inside windows image?

Tags: vpn, powershell, deployment, wds

Just like we can add driver packages to a windows image file can one [add a vpn connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613767.aspx) 
preferably thru [Add-VpnConnection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554824.aspx) inside a .wim file ?

Comment: Which version of Windows? You can create VPN connections by scripting RAS, but I have a feeling you're after Server 2012's ability to add packages to WIMs

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yes. Well, I am trying to deploy Win8.1 clients. Trying th is so end-users don't have to install an additional vpn client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a lot of digging and it looks like CMAK is what you want: generate the exe and have it auto executed by either MDT or unattend.XML.

@Evan Anderson has said:

`You can use this tool to create a program to generate an EXE that automatically configures client computers with a "connection" to your VPN server. We typically deploy it onto client computers using startup scripts with a registry-based versioning mechanism to cause computers to install new versions if we deploy them.`

Cmak stands for `Connection Manager Administation Kit`
You can find it here: [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc752995.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad you liked it!